# How to make wp_enqueue_style and wp_enqueue_script work only on custom post type

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, wp-enqueue-style

How to make wp_enqueue_style and wp_enqueue_script work only on custom post type

I have install plugin on my wordpress that creat custom post type which is "http://localhost/wordpress/manga" and i have other custom post type like "http://localhost/wordpress/anime" so i only want to css work on manga not anime or in the front page

this is the code:
wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-manga-plugin-css', WP_MANGA_URI . 'assets/css/style.css' );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [conditionals](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/):

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_enqueues' );
function wpse_enqueues() {
    // Only enqueue on specified single CPTs
    if( is_singular( array( 'anime', 'manga' ) ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-manga-plugin-css', WP_MANGA_URI . 'assets/css/style.css' );
    }
}
?>
```

If you need the CSS on archives as well, that's another condition:

```
if( is_singular( array( 'anime', 'manga' ) ) || is_post_type_archive( array( 'anime, 'manga' ) ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-manga-plugin-css', WP_MANGA_URI . 'assets/css/style.css' 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for [`is_singular`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_singular/), which you could put in e.g. your theme or functions.php to test for your CPT like:

```
if (is_singular('anime')) {
   wp_enqueue_style( ... ) ; 
}
```